# What is the best way to round a double to 10 digits?

Tags: java, double

I am trying to round a random decimal number to 10 digits but I can't figure out how. Now, this is what I tried and it works most of the times, but sometimes I get it rounded to 9 digits rather then 10. I hope someone could help me.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Math.random()).setScale(10, 0);
double doubleVal = bd.doubleValue();
System.out.println(doubleVal);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have a misunderstanding of numbers and their representation. Numbers itself (which are stored in a `double`-typed variable, for example) cannot be _rounded_ or similar. They are simply numbers. Only the textual representation can be rounded. Usually, you do it with a [formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) or other means.

Comment: What do you think second `0` parameter does in the `setScale()` call? And why to you think so?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Well, to be clear, numbers can be rounded, but I agree that that is not what OP is looking for.

Comment: LiziPizi, if you round the number `3.997` to 2 decimal places, what do you get? `4`, `4.0`, or `4.00`? Answer: All three, because they are all the same *number*. If you want the *number* printed with exactly 2 decimal places, that's *formatting* of the textual representation of the number, not rounding of the number itself.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose What do you mean by representation? can you please elaborate? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say it is sometimes rounded to 9 digits. Does this happen around 10% of the time? Because it could just be that the 10th digit is actually zero after rounding.

Comment: Yes around 10%, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: The value you have ended up with only contains 9 decimal places, as the 10th decimal place is 0. When you print the value, it leaves out the 10th decimal place as it is not required.

Do you require the zero to be output?

Comment: NB: if that is what you need, you can print it with:

System.out.printf("%.10f\n", doubleVal);

Comment: The thing is that I am trying to follow my instructions that my university gave me, it says "Create array of doubles that the number of digits after the point should be rounded to 10 digits so you will need to use an auxiliary method for the rounding". Plus, I already created the radixSort method and I will need to use it on the array. What do you think I should do then?

Comment: @LiziPizi A number with only 9 non-zero digits after the point, *is* a number rounded to 10 digits, so you already have what you need. Now just fix the second argument to `setScale()`, so it's clear what you are trying to do, e.g. did you truly intend to use `ROUND_UP` and not the more normal `ROUND_HALF_UP`, and if so, say that instead of use `0`?